# Write to CSV on first empty line

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I'm developing an application to write lines to a CSV. However, when I run the application a second time, the line that was already written is overwritten with the new line. How can I make it so that the writer writes to the next blank line, not one that already has data in it? I haven't found anything on how to do this. Here's my code below:

```
listsof = [1, 2, 3, 4]
with open('C:/Users/Family3/Downloads/weather.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerow(listsof)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this instead (note the 'a' for append):

```
with open('C:/Users/Family3/Downloads/weather.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerow(listsof)
```

The 'a' [opens the file for appending](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) and does not erase the already existing file with the same name.

Answer (score 2):

It is because, whenever you open your csv file, you never take into account that you *might* already have data in your file. When you load your csvfile into your program, you should *append* your new data to the file instead of just *writing* to it.